# How to connect android app to a printer?

Tags: java, android

I'm building and app that uses printer that is connected through USB or some port.
Now i saw the documentation on this on android studio web site but nothing about connecting the actual printer to the app..

Comment: Talk to the printer manufacturer and ask them what their options are for printing to their printers from Android apps.

Comment: Talk to printer's vendor and if there must be some sdk support from printin from android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bluetooth printer. I think that's the easiest way.